# Spring Boot gives different response while load test(50 users) time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have upgraded the project technology from **Java servlet** to **Spring Boot**. It's working fine for single user transaction mode, but it's not working multiple users test.

**My Project configuration**

UI - angular
Business Logic- Java Spring Boot
back end - No SQL get call
No hibernate

**Session - stateless session**
We don't process based on the user's session. We process only employee id and case id(75 % get request, 25 % post request). it's working fine for single user time. LoadNinja load test run 50 users time - we will get another user's response to me.

My name is Apple if I am requesting for my details(load ninja run the same process for 50 user test simultaneously) to the server , but i am getting response as Orange user's details. Sometimes I am getting a Null pointer exception.

I am unable to trace the cause of the issue - Could you please advise for project configuration changes.

Thanks in advance.

EmployeeController.java

```
package com.apa.documentprocessor.constants;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeservice;
    
    @Autowired
    Employee employee;
    
    @RequestMapping("/getDetails")
    public void getEmployeeDetails() throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {
        
        employee.setEmpId("100");
        employee.setEmpName("Nuno");
        employee.setDept("Research");
        employee.setLocation("India");
        
        
        EmployeePerformance emp = employeeservice.EmployeeDetails(employee);
        
        System.out.println(emp.toString());
        
        
    }
    
}
```

EmployeeService.java

```
package com.apa.documentprocessor.constants;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;


import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;



@Component
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeePerformance empPerformance;
    
    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
    
    public EmployeePerformance EmployeeDetails(Employee emp) throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {
            
        
        this.empPerformance = beanFactory.createBean(EmployeePerformance.class);
        this.empPerformance = getDetails(emp);
        
        
        return empPerformance;
        
    }


    private EmployeePerformance getDetails(Employee emp) throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {
        
        
        String result;
        String url=emp.getEmpName();
        
        
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
        method.addRequestHeader("3454362523", emp.getEmpId());
        
        client.executeMethod(method);
        
        result = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmployeePerformance.class);
        
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        
        EmployeePerformance empPerformance = (EmployeePerformance) jaxbUnmarshaller
                .unmarshal(new InputSource(new StringReader(result)));
        
        
        empPerformance.setProject("Banking");
        empPerformance.setRating("Good");
        
        return empPerformance;
    }
    
    
}
```

EmployeePerformance.java

```
package com.apa.documentprocessor.constants;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmployeePerformance {

    String empName;
    String rating;
    String project;
    String position;
    
    
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getProject() {
        return project;
    }
    public void setProject(String project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    
    
}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.apa.documentprocessor.constants;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Employee {

    
    String empId;
    String empName;
    String dept;
    String location;
    
    
    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you have user specific data as a property in a service? Be aware that spring beans a singletons by default. post some example code

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Looks/feels like sharing state in the controller (which is a singleton) whereas a servlet can be per request. But without seeing code this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you check now.

Comment: @AndreasRadauer Can you check now.

Comment: @ray Can you check now

Comment: Your code is flawed. Don't inject `EmployeePerformance` or `Employee` just create a new instance and return it. The fact that you use spring doesn't mean **everything** needs to be managed by Spring.

Comment: Regarding performance don't use `HttpClient` like that or construct it each time. Instead use the `RestTemplate` provided by Spring Boot and **reuse** it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is flawed, don't make `Employee` nor `EmployeePerformance` spring managed beans. Just construct a new instance when you need one. The fact that one uses Spring doesn't mean **everything** needs to be managed by Spring.

```java
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeservice;
    
    @RequestMapping("/getDetails")
    public void getEmployeeDetails() throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpId("100");
        employee.setEmpName("Nuno");
        employee.setDept("Research");
        employee.setLocation("India");
        
        EmployeePerformance emp = employeeservice.EmployeeDetails(employee);
        
        System.out.println(emp.toString());
    }  
}
```

Regarding the use of `HttpClient` don't construct one each time, instead reuse it, or even better use `RestTemplate` which does all of that out-of-the-box, including the marshalling.

```java
@Component
public class EmployeeService {

    private final RestTemplate http;
    
    public EmployeeService(RestTemplate http) {
      this.http=http;
    }

    public EmployeePerformance EmployeeDetails(Employee emp) throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {           
        return getDetails(emp);
    }

    private EmployeePerformance getDetails(Employee emp) throws HttpException, IOException, JAXBException {
        
        String url=emp.getEmpName();
        RequestEntity req = RequestEntity.get(url).header("3454362523", emp.getEmpId()).build();  
        
        EmployeePerformance empPerformance = http.exchange(req, EmployeePerformance.class).getBody();       
        
        empPerformance.setProject("Banking");
        empPerformance.setRating("Good");
        
        return empPerformance;
    }
}
```

In your configuration you need to add the following

```java
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
  return builder.requestFactory(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class).build();
}
```

With this you are not sharing state anymore and reusing heavy objects instaed of constructing them each time you need them.